# Datepicker in html

Tags: html, forms, datepicker

I have a date fields in my Form and I want user to select the dates from the calendar. however I need to create a datepicker.Searched on net still cant find the best answers.Is it possible to have a date picker in html?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `datepicker` in html with one of `HTML5 Input Types`, but also *(not supported in Internet Explorer)*, For example :

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
        Birthday:
        <input type="date" name="bday">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

See [**DEMO**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date) from [*w3schools.com*](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)